# How to use for loop across various years and get multiple plots together?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, data-wrangling

https://www.kaggle.com/nowke9/ipldata ---- contains the data set.

I am fairly new to R programming. This is an exploratory study performed for the IPL data set. (link for the data attached above) After merging both the files with "id" and "match_id", I am trying to plot the relationship between matches won by teams across different cities.

However, since 12 seasons are over the output which I am getting is not helping to make sufficient conclusions. In order to plot the relationship across each year, it is required to use for loop. Right now, the output for all the 12 years is displayed in a single graph.

How to rectify this mistake and plot a separate graph for each year with proper color scheming ?

```
library(tidyverse)
matches_tbl <- read_csv("data/matches_updated.csv")
deliveries_tbl <- read_csv("data/deliveries_updated.csv")

combined_matches_deliveries_tbl <- deliveries_tbl %>%
    left_join(matches_tbl, by = c("match_id" = "id"))

combined_matches_deliveries_tbl %>%
    group_by(city, winner)%>%
    filter(season == 2008:2019, !result == "no result")%>%
    count(match_id)%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = winner))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill = city),alpha = 0.5, color = "black", position = "stack")+
    coord_flip()+
    theme_bw()
```

The output is as follows:-

```
  There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
  [Winner of teams across cities for the years between 2008 and 2019][1]
```

The required output is :- 12 separate graphs in a single code with proper color scheming. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: in your `filter` can you change `season == 2008:2019` to `season %in% 2008:2019`

Comment: It is not working. The output is the same as before.

Comment: maybe [`facet_wrap()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) in **ggplot2** is working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `mtcars` to split by a variable into separate plots. What I created is a scatter plot of `vs` and `mpg` by splitting the dataset by `cyl`. First create an empty list. Then I use lapply to loop through the values of cyl (4,6,8) and then filter the data by that value. After that I plot the scatter plot for the subset and save it to the empty list. Each segment of the list will represent a plot and you can pull them out as you see fit.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
gglist <- list()

gglist <- lapply(c(4,6,8), function(x){

ggplot(filter(mtcars, cyl == x))+
    geom_point(aes(x=vs,y=mpg))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
combined_matches_deliveries_tbl %>%
  group_by(city, winner,season)%>%
  filter(season %in% 2008:2019, !result == "no result")%>%
  count(match_id)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = winner))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = city),alpha = 0.5, color = "black", position = "stack")+
  coord_flip()+ facet_wrap(season~.)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good. But can it be done separately using for loop ?

Comment: Why do you need looping? `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` will do the job of looping. You wanted 12 years is displayed in a single graph. `facet_wrap`  did the job for you.